# Could we build sth similar to Java NIO from Java IO?

Tags: java, io, network-programming, netty, nio

I see that Java NIO is quite complicated. Could we create sth from Java IO that achieves the purpose of Java NIO?

I think it is easy to make buffer oriented and non-blocking IO - two main features of Java NIO. We could read data from stream into buffer instead of handling them immediately. About non-blocking IO, we could use setSoTimeout method of Java IO to allow a thread to give up waiting after an amount of time (e.g. 100ms).Based on that, we can create a thread that handle multiple connections.

If it is easy like above, is Java NIO redundant?

Comment: No. There's a big difference between 100mS and zero, or even 1mS and zero. You could not implement `select()` efficiently with read timeouts.

Comment: OK, I give up, what is "sth"?

Comment: I wonder how Java NIO identifies if data in a channel is available or not? Doesn't it wait for data for a period of time?

Comment: @PeterPhan No. It calls `select(2)` or one of the `poll()` variants.

Comment: "I think it is easy": the famous first words of everyone who thinks about simple solutions to problems they don't understand completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, the solution you are proposing might appear to work. However, it would be just a simulation, and could never be as efficient as the actual NIO implementation.

The reason for this is that NIO works essentially different that Java IO. This "advanced" part requires support in operating system. When you're only working with small amounts of data, 10ms doesn't look much different than 60ms. But as others have said, an I/O that takes 10 seconds instead of 1 minute makes a world of difference.

There are several other subtleties, too. Socket timeout is not the same as waiting for data. Asynchronous I/O does not neccessarily use many threads. Typically, one thread per hardware device is enough. There is no waiting involved. There are fewer context switches. The data is processed as efficiently as possible, which includes not copying it from one buffer into another if that can be avoided. In the end, it all adds up.

Comment: Could you explain more about support in OS? What are they?

Comment: @PeterPhan With normal IO, you need to have 1 thread per channel to make sure you have the minimal delay. With NIO, you give the operation system a list of sockets, and it then waits till any of the channels have data (see man page of `select(2)`), and you can then quickly query how much data every channel has, and only act on the channels that have data

Comment: Oh "select(2)" again. Is it a java method? I search google but there is no relevance found

Comment: The general idea is to treat I/O devices as autonomous. For example, you give disk a command to read a range of sectors directly into memory then leave it alone. When finished, disk will set an interrupt flag so that CPU will know it needs servicing. This is achieved using selectors (a mechanism for examining status), buffers (a wrapper around physical memory region) and channels (an abstraction of a device capable of reading/writing data). Behind the scenes, this uses hardware features such as interrupts and DMA. The OS provides hardware abstraction, whereas Java NIO provides OS abstraction.